# The OLE DB provider for linked server supplied inconsistent metadata for a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

The error I get is:

```
The column "EngDescAlt" (compile-time ordinal 2) of object "select * from MstBusiness" was reported to have a "DBCOLUMNFLAGS_ISLONG" of 128 at compile time and 0 at run time.
```

I get the same error for various columns in a couple of tables, the only difference each time is the column name and the table name, and I cant figure out how to fix it. Any ideas?

Just by the way using OpenQuery doesnt work as that is what I was already using.

Any help is appreciated.

```
SELECT     Z_ID AS BusinessID, EngDescAlt AS Description
FROM         OPENQUERY(<LinkedServer>, 'select * from <Tablename>') AS U2_<Tablename>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "compile time" and "run time" here?  What environment is executing the OpenQuery?  Can you execute the following from Management Studio, and from an OpenQuery, and in each case what do you get:  SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  WHERE TABLE_NAME='MstBusiness' AND COLUMN_NAME='EngDescAlt'

Comment: I dont exactly know what compile time and run time are. Im using SSMS 2012. Yes I can but no information is returned.

Comment: [oops.. point (4) corrected] (1) It could help if you added your query to the question... (though you probably want to put <serverName>.<databaseName> instead of your actual values). (2) When you say you get "no information" running your query in SSMS 2012, do you mean zero rows? (3) Can you run a trace in SQL Profiler, on the target server, while your query executes? Does it show any query executing? (4) If you specify the databasename, in the query I gave before, what do you get?: SELECT * FROM <database>.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='MstBusiness' AND COLUMN_NAME='EngDescAlt'

Comment: 2) Yes, no data was returned. 3) I dont know what that is or how to do that sorry, im really new to all this. 4) I get no rows returned aswell.

Comment: Re' (3) I don't know if exactly the same in SQL Server 2012, but try:  click "Start", "All Programs", "Microsoft SQL Server 2012", "Performance Tools", and then "SQL Server Profiler".  I suggest you google "SQL Server Profiler" for steps, but this might be enough for now:  click "File" and "New Trace", connect to server, and on the "Trace Properties" window select tab "Events Selection".  Find & select the check box "Show all columns".  Click the "Column Filters" button.  On the left click DatabaseName; on the right expand "Like", & enter "MstBusiness". Click "OK".  Click "Run".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just noticed you edited your question, posting your query.
A great way to debug, is to test small steps toward your goal... so you can see exactly which step introduces an error.

First, can you connect directly to the target server, to test your queries without OPENQUERY?
If so, then try the simple select from within SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio):

```
SELECT Z_ID AS BusinessID, EngDescAlt AS Description  
FROM <Tablename>
```

If that works, try:

```
SELECT Z_ID AS BusinessID, EngDescAlt AS Description 
FROM (select * from <Tablename>) AS U2_<Tablename>
```

And try running the openquery in SSMS, in a query window that is connected *directly* to that target server (rather than as a linked server):

```
SELECT Z_ID AS BusinessID, EngDescAlt AS Description
FROM OPENQUERY(<LinkedServer>, 'select * from <Tablename>') AS U2_<Tablename>
```

Finally, a question:  what environment have you been running the OPENQUERY in?  Has it been from within SSMS on another server / your workstation?  Or has it been from some other environment/language/tool?  If you haven't been executing the openquery in SSMS, try that too, accessing as a linked server.

And please report back the results and/or messages.

Comment: Its all been in SSMS. Thanks I'll give this a try :)

Answer (score 2):

For some reason restarting MS SQL SERVICES on the server fixed the problem. It seems it had something to do with a problem that was fixed and required a restart to enact. Sorry I cant be more specific as to what fixed the problem.

Comment: In that case, was it generous of you to make my answer, as an answer?  Did breaking it into steps, (like, first trying queries on a direct connection to the target server, before trying access as a linked server), help somehow, in identifying where the problem was?